# Expression must be a modifiable value in C

Tags: c

```
void lowerit(char line[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; line[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z') ? line[i] = line[i] - 'A' + 'a' : line[i] = line[i];
    }
}
```

Pretty simple code..
For some reason I am getting error in visual studio at the beginning of inside for loop.
(Line[i]  <--- this causes "Expression must be a modifiable value" error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I change it to if else statement, it works fine.if (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z')
   line[i] = line[i] - 'A' + 'a';

Comment: Notice than `'A'`-`'Z'` is not guarantied to be contiguous (as for [EBCDIC](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code)), so not portable.

Comment: Why not just `line[i] = tolower(line[i]);` from `<ctype.h>`?

Comment: @Blaze's solution is not only simpler, it's more portable. Not all C implementations use character encodings that offer consecutive alphabet character values.

Comment: Compile fine on gcc/clang BTW [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/079623eec4e9fb3e)

Comment: @Jarod42 - the question is not about C++.

Comment: @rustyx: tag has been removed... (I'm follow [tag:C++] not [tag:C]).

Comment: One solution (although by no means the best solution) is to wrap the two assignments in parentheses: `(line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z') ? (line[i] = line[i] - 'A' + 'a') : (line[i] = line[i]);`

Comment: @IanAbbott: Indeed, note you can also drop the ones at the start. Consider answering based on that? I'd upvote it.

Comment: The best solution is to use an if-else statement. `?:` comes with hidden implicit promotion. `auto cpp11fail = condition ? line[i] = line[i] - 'A' + 'a' : line[i];` means you end up with an `int` instead of `char` as expected, even when condition is false. While `else { auto less_bad = line[i]; }` results in a `char` as expected.

Comment: @Lundin: Add (aside from using `tolower`) before your 5 minutes is up?

Comment: @Bathsheba Well, obviously, but this seems to be yet another artificial school exercise.

Comment: Please do not use the `?:` operator as a control structure - that's what `if` statements are for.

Answer (score 8):

You need to write the ternary conditional as

```
line[i] = line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z' ? line[i] - 'A' + 'a' : line[i];
```

although since the `:` branch is a no-op a simple `if` is to be preferred.

Because `=` and the ternary conditional have the same precedence and associativity (although the latter can be considered as fictionally elevated insofar that the middle part is evaluated as if it's in parentheses), the expression you have is not grouped the way you are expecting it, which explains the compiler diagnostic. In fact, it's grouped as

```
((line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z') ? line[i] = line[i] - 'A' + 'a' : line[i]) = line[i];
```

which, interestingly, is valid C++, but not valid C.

Finally, the expression you've written looks like a non-portable version of the standard library function `tolower`, which you should use instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. That explained it all!

Comment: Ternary and assignment do not have the same precedence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Aside from the fact that the middle part of the ternary is evaluated as if it's in parentheses, yes they do. What's made you take the opposing view?

Comment: Go look at the precedence table in your C textbook.  They’re given different precedences.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: My reading is that it's fictionally elevated, which I've now mentioned. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's fictional, but I'll leave alone from here.  There isn't a lot of difference in precedence, but there is a difference.  K&R lists the ternary (conditional) operator at one level above the assignment operators.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This is worth looking at, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Note 2 is not very helpful; note 3 is accurate enough.  The operator has a different precedence level from assignment, but the interpretation of the middle leads to traps on occasion.  In the standard, the ternary is given a separate precedence level, because it is given a separate section.  I don't think the site is helping anyone.  OK: discussion closed — we'll have to agree to disagree (or, if you wish, you can continue to disagree, but I'm not going to get further involved).  Bar one URL in the next comment.

Comment: The C standard defines the [conditional operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15) (ternary operator) before the [assignment operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16).  That means it has higher precedence as far as the standard is concerned.